# Kubernetes installation on Rhel7 AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, installation, kubernetes, rhel7

I'm trying to install Kubernetes on a brand new Amazon Ec2 with Rhel7 Os running. I have zero knowledge on Kubernetes and trying to learn it. Please help with process of installation.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way of bootstrapping a kubernetes cluster in AWS is through the use of kops (https://github.com/kubernetes/kops).

You can also check kubeadm or kubespray.